# jquery validate - Looping through dynamic forms with array() of form name['id'][name2]

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this form https://jsfiddle.net/y2L3rcts/2/ which dynamically adds input boxes to the form when a user clicks "Add More".

The initial input boxes has the following `name=` meta:

```
label[0][name]
label[0][left]
```

Adding new input boxes dynamically creates new input boxes with `name=`

```
label[1][name]
label[1][left]
```

and so on...

Validating the initial input boxes can be easily done using query rules:

```
//Form Validation
         $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                "label[0][name]": {
                    required: true
                },
                "label[0][left]": {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

And, validating the additional "Add More" input boxes can be done by explicitly declaring those `label[id]` at the rules even they do not exist at the form.

```
"label[0][name]": {
    required: true
},
"label[0][left]": {
    required: true
},
// Add the "Add More" input box labels assuming they do exist
"label[1][name]": {
    required: true
},
"label[1][left]": {
    required: true
},
"label[2][name]": {
    required: true
},
"label[2][left]": {
    required: true
}
```

and so on. But this method is static. There is no limit on how many `"Add more"` input boxes can be dynamically created, so it would be inefficient to define explicitly all `label[id]` (say, 99) in our rules.

is there a way for Jquery Validator to check how many input boxes with `label[]` are created and apply the rules to all of them?

BTW, I tried modifying my own `jquery.validator.js` as per suggested by this: http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/05/27/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input-elements/ But I am still in no luck, i don't think that problem's scope cover my problem.

Hope somebody can help. Thanks!

(P.S. I'd been working for couple of hours in fiddle on how can i make the validation work there, haha, i have no idea how you guys do it)

Comment: The developer has provided [the `rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) so you can dynamically add rules to elements _after_ you create them.  Simply refer to the documentation.

Comment: *"is there a way for Jquery Validator to check how many input boxes with label[]"* ~  Yes, use a jQuery "starts with" selector, a jQuery `.each()` and the `rules('add')` method.  Like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/4sppppa8/1/

Comment: @Sparky thank you very much for leading me the right path. it seems like the question I should have ask is "selecting input added dynamically, then applying jquery validation for each". I have solved with the help of your jsfiddle code but it still needed me to put the initial `input name` there. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, simply including the `required="required"` attribute on the `input` itself renders the issue moot.  The plugin will automatically pickup and use the `required` attributes accordingly.  It just depends on which rules need to be applied.

Comment: @Sparky its fine, I have other `rules` needed like `max` and `min` length